# Ubuntu SSH. ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Добрый вечер, есть такая проблема. У меня на работе корпоративная сеть, я через впн имею доступ к своему компу из дома. Пинги до рабочего компа идут. Поставил на работе openssh server, сразу же подконнектился к нему по ssh, все вроде замечательно. Замечательно было до перезагрузки рабочего компа. После перезагрузки не смог подсоединиться, получил вот такую штуку:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.180.67 [xxx.xxx.180.67] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hacktivist/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

**ifconfig на сервере:**

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:60:6e:80:cd:26
    inet addr:xxx.xxx.180.67  Bcast:xxx.xxx.180.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::a60:6eff:fe80:cd26/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:102629 errors:0 dropped:10860 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:34422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:35816123 (35.8 MB)  TX bytes:4372133 (4.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
    RX packets:44326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:44326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    RX bytes:27682920 (27.6 MB)  TX bytes:27682920 (27.6 MB)
```

Строка debug1: Connection established. как бы намекает, мол соединение установлено, но ничего такого на самом деле нет.

Запускал /usr/sbin/ssh -ddd, он стартует и молчит. Говорит, мол слушаю 0.0.0.0 на порту 22. Все, после этого никакой реакции нет при попытки подключиться с клиента. Я просто получаю ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer, а на сервере не появляется абсолютно ни одной строчки лога. По /var/log/auth.log и security ничего нет.
hosts.deny пустой, hosts.allow тоже пустой, хотя пробовал добавлять туда sshd: ALL, бесполезно.
Сам к себе на сервере я подключаюсь, а с домашнего не могу. Я бы грешил на то, что мол маршруты кривые, либо нет доступа из под впн, если бы сам лично не подключился к себе ДО ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗКИ. У кого-нибудь есть варианты?
убунта 16.04

Comment: вариантов более чем достаточно: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151860/110559

Comment: первое, что я бы лично проверил: исключил «слабое звено» в виде чего-то, что вы назвали «впн»: ssh-соединения отлично туннелируются через ssh-соединения без какой-либо «сетевой виртуализации.

Answer (score 0):

Дело может быть из-за ошибки в маршрутизации. Когда запрос на подключение идёт по одному маршруту, а ответ возвращается по другому. Например ушёл по WAN, а возвращается по VLAN ил LAN. Если смотреть на состояние соединений - то инициализация проходит, но не заканчивается. В итоге указанное сообщение об ошибке